# diff two rpms? -- linux

Tags: linux, diff, rpm

Some unknown changes were made to my baseline (java/ C++) and installed in a new rpm. I would like a way to compare the content of this rpm with an old one to see the changes made. Is this possible?

If there is no easy way to do this, is there a way to get a content list of rpm file names within it organized by date?

Comment: If your rpm package has changelog, you can run the command `rpm --changelog -q mypackage` and it will display the changelog of the currently installed `mypackage`.

Comment: If you just want to get the list of files in the package with dates, you can run `rpm -qlv mypackage`.

Comment: When I run these commands it returns: package myRPM.rpm is not installed. I am running as root and have verified installed packages by using: rpm -q -a |grep myRPM

Comment: Drop the extension `.rpm`. The command should be `rpm -qlv myRPM`, or whatever the whole package name was displayed when grepping for `myRPM`. Example would be `rpm -qlv kernel-uek` or `rpm -qlv kernel-uek-2.6.32-400.1.1.el5uek`.

Comment: Cool that works now. However when I run the command it only tells me when the jars were updated, I actually need to see the update dates of files within the jars. I suppose this will just require another step of viewing jar contents though. This should help, thanks!

Comment: If you need to get the list of classes and files inside the jar file you can run `unzip -l myjar.jar`. This will list the contents of the file `myjar.jar`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [pkgdiff](https://github.com/lvc/pkgdiff) to visualize differences between RPM packages:

```
pkgdiff PKG-0.rpm PKG-1.rpm
```

If you compare SRC.RPM then the tool will extract and compare the internal tarball too (unless the *-skip-subarchives* option is defined).

[image]

[image]

Comment: User [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14394735/matt) states: _I get this output from pkgdiff: reading packages ... ERROR: unknown format "rpm"_

Answer (score 4):

To rigorously compare two rpm files (let's call them *one.rpm* and *another.rpm*), you'll want to check the [digests of the constituent files](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2003-March/msg00292.html) as well as check the [pre- and post-[un]install scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121867/where-are-rpm-postinstall-scripts-located) (because these scripts might modify the system state):

`$ diff <(rpm -q --dump --scripts -p one.rpm) <(rpm -q --dump --scripts -p another.rpm)`

You might also want to compare the [signatories](http://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/5/RHEL-5-manual/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-check-rpm-sig.html) (if there are any):

`$ diff <(rpm -q --qf '%{SIGPGP:pgpsig}\n%{SIGPGP:armor}\n' -p one.rpm) <(rpm -q --qf '%{SIGPGP:pgpsig}\n%{SIGPGP:armor}\n' -p another.rpm)`

(or, [if you're especially pedantic](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/44334/how-i-list-unsigned-packages-of-my-fedora-system/?answer=44443#post-id-44443):

`$ diff <(rpm -q --qf '%{DSAHEADER:pgpsig}\n%{DSAHEADER:armor}\n%{RSAHEADER:pgpsig}\n%{DSAHEADER:armor}\n%{SIGGPG:pgpsig}\n%{SIGGPG:armor}\n%{SIGPGP:pgpsig}\n%{SIGPGP:armor}\n' -p one.rpm) <(rpm -q --qf '%{DSAHEADER:pgpsig}\n%{DSAHEADER:armor}\n%{RSAHEADER:pgpsig}\n%{DSAHEADER:armor}\n%{SIGGPG:pgpsig}\n%{SIGGPG:armor}\n%{SIGPGP:pgpsig}\n%{SIGPGP:armor}\n' -p another.rpm)`

)

Comment: This is the only answer that describes how to compare package scripts. Why down vote it? There are times when the only differences between package releases are in the scripts. While this answer is incomplete in itself it does complement other incomplete answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the previous rpm package file, you can unpack that, e.g., using [`unrpm`](http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-legacy-list/2004-February/msg00132.html) into a temporary directory and use `diff -r` to compare the results.

Here is an example, which I made to illustrate, between two development versions of ncurses:

```
#!/bin/sh

failed() {
    echo "? $*" >&2
    exit 1
}

# get the package filename as parameter, defaulting to one used for example
oldpkg=$(readlink -f "${1:-/tmp/ncurses6-6.0-20150926.x86_64.rpm}")
pkgname=$(rpm -qip "$oldpkg" 2>/dev/null | awk '/^Name .*:/ { print $3; exit 0; }')

[ -f "$oldpkg" ] || failed "no package file found: $oldpkg"
[ -n "$pkgname" ] || failed "no package name found in $oldpkg"

# The tags for this question are "linux" and "rpm", so mktemp and bash are assumed.
tempdir=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/pkgcompare.XXXXXX")
trap 'rm -rf "$tempdir"' EXIT ERR

# Fedora sets CDPATH, which would echo (cancel that).
unset CDPATH

mkdir -p "$tempdir"/{new-version,old-version}

cd "$tempdir/new-version" || exit
# the query returns absolute pathnames beginning with "/"
rpm -ql "$pkgname" | while :
do
    read path
    [ -z "$path" ] && break
    [ -d "$path" ] && mkdir -p ".$path"
    [ -f "$path" ] && mkdir -p "./${path%/*}"
    [ -f "$path" ] && cp -p "$path" ".$path"
done

cd "$tempdir/old-version" || exit
rpm2cpio "$oldpkg" | cpio -i -d 2>/dev/null

cd $tempdir || exit
# I would usually pipe this into diffstat, but you may want the actual diffs
diff -r -u -N old-version new-version | diffstat
```

and output (only the [diffstat](http://invisible-island.net/diffstat/diffstat.html) is left, other output suppressed):

```
 bin/ncursesw6-config           |    2 +-
 include/ncursesw6/curses.h     |    8 ++++----
 include/ncursesw6/ncurses.h    |    8 ++++----
 lib64/libncurses++w6.so        |binary
 lib64/libncurses++w6.so.6      |binary
 lib64/libncurses++w6.so.6.0    |binary
 lib64/libncursesw6.so          |binary
 lib64/libncursesw6.so.6        |binary
 lib64/libncursesw6.so.6.0      |binary
 lib64/libtinfow6.so            |binary
 lib64/libtinfow6.so.6          |binary
 lib64/libtinfow6.so.6.0        |binary
 lib64/pkgconfig/formw6.pc      |    2 +-
 lib64/pkgconfig/menuw6.pc      |    2 +-
 lib64/pkgconfig/ncurses++w6.pc |    2 +-
 lib64/pkgconfig/ncursesw6.pc   |    2 +-
 lib64/pkgconfig/panelw6.pc     |    2 +-
 lib64/pkgconfig/ticw6.pc       |    2 +-
 lib64/pkgconfig/tinfow6.pc     |    2 +-
 19 files changed, 16 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)
```

You could of course apply the same approach to two rpm packages; the question made it apparent that one is installed, and the other may be accessible.

Comment: Would you mind if I take a pass through the code for best practices? (Quoting expansions, aborting on `cd` failure, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor, using variable names compliant with http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html conventions, etc)?

Comment: go ahead - that was just a quick example (now that you remind me, I see a a couple of places to quote)

Comment: That will work when dealing with source packages. When dealing with binary files, you can't really compare the contents and display the difference. Maybe make a note of it in your answer so future readers will not be surprised.

Comment: @alvits, it's comparing against files on the local filesystem, so I wouldn't exactly say that it works with source package as-is. :)

Comment: @ThomasDickey, I decided I didn't want to make overlarge changes without your explicit review and approval, so I'm just providing https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/af955e20662a558c2f95/revisions as a gist. showing a proposed diff.

Comment: @charles-duffy: thanks - I'll take a look (and retest...). @alvits: as noted, I'd start with `diffstat` which follows `diff` in just noting that a change was made to a binary file.   OP probably had no expectation that a binary-diff tool would be used.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - what I meant by source packages, is not where the package came from. What I meant by source package is really a set of source files, the C++ and java source files which are ASCII files. As an example, I won't compare `ncurse.rpm` with another binary `ncurse.rpm` but I will compare `ncurse.src.rpm` with another `ncurse.src.rpm`. I guess I should not use the word source but rather use the word devel.

Comment: @alvits, I know what you meant -- I used to be in charge of packaging for MontaVista's Linux distro, which used RPM. But this script **doesn't** compare two RPMs, so it couldn't possibly be used to compare two source RPMs (unless you made a habit of installing your source RPMs, which most folks don't); it compares one RPM against the set of locally-installed files.

Comment: @alvits, ...if you wanted to write a script to compare two source RPMs, at minimum, you'd want to expand and then delete the source archives the contained in both.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - You are absolutely right that the `.src.rpm` package still needs to be expanded. I wasn't suggesting comparing RPMs directly, although I was using the name to differentiate binary from source packages. I was just trying to explain the word `source` which I thought was misunderstood.

Comment: Not just the `src.rpm` package, but the tarballs within it. Though because the tool provided in this answer is built to run against packaged RPMs, it doesn't need to deal with that kind of recursion.

Comment: Thanks guys for taking the time to write this out! I have used the answer in the comments as it seemed quicker to try and got the job done for me. This seems like a better approach should I continue to need to do this in the future. I am hesitant to accept this without trying so I will wait to accept until I have tried it myself or it receives more up votes. Hopefully it will help others as well. Thanks again!

Comment: Code uses `diff -r`, while first paragraph uses `diff -R` (which doesn't exist at least in CentOS 6.6, diff v2.8.1). Would've updated quick, but "blah blah 6 characters blah"...